# in Matlab, what A(1) means? if A is a Matrix

Tags: matlab

I'm new for Matlab, and there is a question confusing me.

if A is a matrix that, `A = [4 2; 2 3; 3 4]`

what A(1) means?

```
A(1) = 4
A(2) = 2
A(3) = 3
A(4) = 2
A(5) = 3
A(6) = 4
```

and A(7) get an error: Index exceeds the number of array elements (6).

Wondering if A(1) means the 1st element, then why A(3) and A(4) not in the correct order?

thanks!

Comment: They are in the correct order, MATLAB is column-major. You can read it in the docs: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-2

Comment: As to your title, what `A(1)` means can be found in the first duplicate, this is called *linear indexing*. As to the actual question, "are `A(3)` and `A(4)` swapped?", that boils down to understanding row major vs column major. See the second duplicate for that, or the link @AnderBiguri provided.

Comment: Thanks both of you: Ander Biguri and Adriaan :-)